# Windows 10 Kiosk Modus with Custom shell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I would like to setup a Kiosk Modus where user is logged on and Browser starts automatically.

[Windows Custom Shell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#icd)

```
$COMPUTER = "localhost"
$NAMESPACE = "root\standardcimv2\embedded"

# Create a handle to the class instance so we can call the static methods.
$ShellLauncherClass = [wmiclass]"\\$COMPUTER\${NAMESPACE}:WESL_UserSetting"


# This well-known security identifier (SID) corresponds to the BUILTIN\Administrators group.

$Admins_SID = "S-1-5-32-544"

# Create a function to retrieve the SID for a user account on a machine.

function Get-UsernameSID($AccountName) {

    $NTUserObject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($AccountName)
    $NTUserSID = $NTUserObject.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

    return $NTUserSID.Value

}

# Get the SID for a user account named "Cashier". Rename "Cashier" to an existing account on your system to test this script.

$Kiosk_SID = Get-UsernameSID("Kiosk")

# Define actions to take when the shell program exits.

$restart_shell = 0
$restart_device = 1
$shutdown_device = 2

# Set Internet Explorer as the shell for "Cashier", and restart the machine if it's closed.

$ShellLauncherClass.SetCustomShell($Kiosk_SID, "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe www.google.com", ($null), ($null), $restart_shell)

# Enable Shell Launcher

$ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($TRUE)
```

When i execute this powershell script and logon with kiosk i only see a black screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so complicated?

Windows allows you to set a custom user interface via one registry line or with the help of Group Policys.

GPO:

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Custom User Interface
```

Here you can set e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -k www.google.de
```

This will not only open the Internet Explorer instead of explorer as user interface, IE will also be full screen (the -k option).

Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Here you need a REG_SZ Item with the same content as above. If the "system" Key does not exist, create it. And since this is done in the "Current User" Hive, this will only affect the user that is logged on at the moment.

I am using this on some kiosk computers where only one specific site should be accessible, and it works fine (i use a domain computer, so i am using the GPO method).

Comment: This functionality seems to be removed from Windows 10.  I tried and there is no GPO setting called "Custom User Interface" and the registry setting doesn't work.    More info: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/95f83c74-fc63-4ab7-b9ff-3cbaa09520a2/windows-10-pro-client-does-not-work-as-a-kiosk-pc-with-server-2012-r2-gpocustom-user-interface?forum=win10itprosetup

Comment: If you don't want to change your current user, you can create a new one and add user-specific policies only for that user. Here's a good tutorial how to do it: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/80043-apply-local-group-policy-specific-user-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 3):

The GPO option still exists in Windows 10, at least the Enterprise and Pro versions. The path that @Tobias listed is still correct. It's in the main page of System and not in a sub-folder.

[image: Local Group Policy Editor]

[image: Custom User Interface Option]

Answer (score 2):

This has been replaced in Windows 10 with a feature known as `Shell Launcher`, using it you can configure a Win32 app to launch instead of Explorer.

What's more, Windows can even be configured to automatically restart the application upon closure, or to even reboot the PC if the app is somehow barred from opening!  This was specifically created for the 'Point of Sale' / kiosk computer scenario to ensure a hands-off approach in which a device will just always run one and only one app.

**Note**
This approach **requires** an Enterprise or Education SKU of Windows.

> Requirements
> Windows 10 Enterprise or Windows 10 Education.

[Here's some more info on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher).  ]

In short, you can use PowerShell to configure your shell launcher app of choice like so:

```perl
# Check if shell launcher license is enabled
function Check-ShellLauncherLicenseEnabled
{
    [string]$source = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class CheckShellLauncherLicense
{
    const int S_OK = 0;

    public static bool IsShellLauncherLicenseEnabled()
    {
        int enabled = 0;

        if (NativeMethods.SLGetWindowsInformationDWORD("EmbeddedFeature-ShellLauncher-Enabled", out enabled) != S_OK) {
            enabled = 0;
        }
        return (enabled != 0);
    }

    static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("Slc.dll")]
        internal static extern int SLGetWindowsInformationDWORD([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string valueName, out int value);
    }

}
"@

    $type = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -PassThru

    return $type[0]::IsShellLauncherLicenseEnabled()
}

[bool]$result = $false

$result = Check-ShellLauncherLicenseEnabled
"`nShell Launcher license enabled is set to " + $result
if (-not($result))
{
    "`nThis device doesn&#39;t have required license to use Shell Launcher"
    exit
}

$COMPUTER = "localhost"
$NAMESPACE = "root\standardcimv2\embedded"

# Create a handle to the class instance so we can call the static methods.
try {
    $ShellLauncherClass = [wmiclass]"\\$COMPUTER\${NAMESPACE}:WESL_UserSetting"
    } catch [Exception] {
    write-host $_.Exception.Message; 
    write-host "Make sure Shell Launcher feature is enabled"
    exit
    }


# This well-known security identifier (SID) corresponds to the BUILTIN\Administrators group.

$Admins_SID = "S-1-5-32-544"

# Create a function to retrieve the SID for a user account on a machine.

function Get-UsernameSID($AccountName) {

    $NTUserObject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($AccountName)
    $NTUserSID = $NTUserObject.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

    return $NTUserSID.Value
}

# Get the SID for a user account named "Cashier". Rename "Cashier" to an existing account on your system to test this script.

$Cashier_SID = Get-UsernameSID("Cashier")

# Define actions to take when the shell program exits.

$restart_shell = 0
$restart_device = 1
$shutdown_device = 2
$do_nothing = 3

# Examples. You can change these examples to use the program that you want to use as the shell.

# This example sets the command prompt as the default shell, and restarts the device if the command prompt is closed. 

$ShellLauncherClass.SetDefaultShell("cmd.exe", $restart_device)

# Display the default shell to verify that it was added correctly.

$DefaultShellObject = $ShellLauncherClass.GetDefaultShell()

"`nDefault Shell is set to " + $DefaultShellObject.Shell + " and the default action is set to " + $DefaultShellObject.defaultaction

# Set Internet Explorer as the shell for "Cashier", and restart the machine if Internet Explorer is closed.

$ShellLauncherClass.SetCustomShell($Cashier_SID, "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe www.microsoft.com", ($null), ($null), $restart_shell)

# Set Explorer as the shell for administrators.

$ShellLauncherClass.SetCustomShell($Admins_SID, "explorer.exe")

# View all the custom shells defined.

"`nCurrent settings for custom shells:"
Get-WmiObject -namespace $NAMESPACE -computer $COMPUTER -class WESL_UserSetting | Select Sid, Shell, DefaultAction

# Enable Shell Launcher

$ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($TRUE)

$IsShellLauncherEnabled = $ShellLauncherClass.IsEnabled()

"`nEnabled is set to " + $IsShellLauncherEnabled.Enabled

# Remove the new custom shells.

$ShellLauncherClass.RemoveCustomShell($Admins_SID)

$ShellLauncherClass.RemoveCustomShell($Cashier_SID)

# Disable Shell Launcher

$ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($FALSE)

$IsShellLauncherEnabled = $ShellLauncherClass.IsEnabled()

"`nEnabled is set to " + $IsShellLauncherEnabled.Enabled
```

Comment: I guess a day is pretty long where you're form.

Comment: Good point @user1969903, I updated it just now.  It only took me six years!

Comment: Well, better late than never :)